# Redundant rows in SQL Select with Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join

I would like to ask if there's a way to modify my SQL Select statement to prevent the redundant rows as shown below.

```
SELECT tblIssueCommsItem.ItemID, cardNo, tblIssueCommsEqp.currentQty FROM tblIssueCommsItem 
INNER JOIN tblCommsItem ON tblIssueCommsItem.ItemID = tblCommsItem.ItemID 
INNER JOIN tblIssueCommsEqp ON tblIssueCommsItem.EqpID = tblIssueCommsEqp.EqpID  
INNER JOIN tblSetInfo ON tblSetInfo.EqpID = tblIssueCommsEqp.EqpID 
WHERE SetID = 11 AND (cardNo = 'TK 14' OR cardNo = '') AND cardNo != 'Unassigned' 
AND tblIssueCommsItem.VoucherNo = 10006102 AND tblIssueCommsEqp.currentQty > 0
ORDER BY cardNo, serial
```

What I get:

```
ItemID: 1386, cardNO: *blank*, currentQty: 10
ItemID: 1386, cardNO: *blank*, currentQty: 1
ItemID: 1387, cardNO: *blank*, currentQty: 10
ItemID: 1387, cardNO: *blank*, currentQty: 1
ItemID: 1101, cardNO: TK 14, currentQty: 10
ItemID: 1101, cardNO: TK 14, currentQty: 1
ItemID: 2575, cardNO: TK 14, currentQty: 10
ItemID: 2575, cardNO: TK 14, currentQty: 1
```

`SetInfo` contains the different `EqpIDs` that belong to a set. In this case the set is of `SetID` 11. What I want to achieve is the following:

```
ItemID: 1386, cardNO: *blank*, currentQty: 10
ItemID: 1387, cardNO: *blank*, currentQty: 10
ItemID: 1101, cardNO: TK 14, currentQty: 10
ItemID: 2575, cardNO: TK 14, currentQty: 10
```

I realized the redundant rows only occurs when I have more than 1 item in a set whereby the `cardNO = 'TK 14'`. As you can see, the redundant rows are the ones with `currentQty = 1`. There's no such record in my database. I think it's only shown as 1 because it's an `int` field. With `currentQty` being different, these are not really duplicate rows and hence I cannot use `DISTINCT` to get rid of it.

My concept of `JOIN` is not good, but I have tried all kinds of `JOIN` and it produces the exact same results.

Any help appreciated!

UPDATE: PROBLEM SOLVED. Thanks to the people who clarify on the behaviour of SQL of not providing a default integer. `tblIssueCommsEqp.*`, helped me identify the culprit, and realized that I need both `tblIssueCommsEqp.VoucherNo = 10000602 and tblIssueCommsItem.VoucherNo = 1000602` to get what I want.

As my concepts are still weak, I'm still not sure why though that if I have only 1 item of 'TK 14' in a set, everything works as per normal.

For the answers which helped amend my statement, those may potentially work too, but they are sort of cheating, which I will only use it as a last resort.

Comment: There must be row(s) in tblIssueCommsEqp that have currentQty = 1 if that comes to the result. If you add tblIssueCommsEqp.* into the select you should be able to figure out what row it is. Also, check the primary keys / unique constraints in the tables to check if one of them is missing from the join.

Comment: "`the redundant rows are the ones with currentQty as 1. There's no such record in my database.`" Look again. There **must** be records in the database where `currentQty = 1`. Even if the database were just going to fill a default integer (which it _won't_ do), the default integer is 0, not 1.

Comment: Thanks for the help, JamesZ and Joel. tblIssueCommsEqp.* is new to me, and it really helped me out since I have too much records. Please put it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming SQL Server, something like:

```
 group by tblIssueCommsItem.ItemID, cardNo, tblIssueCommsEqp.currentQty
 having max(tblIssueCommsEqp.currentQty)
```

Not sure that will work with order by but should get you in the right direction hopefully :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
SELECT
  tblIssueCommsItem.ItemID,
  cardNo,
  MAX(tblIssueCommsEqp.currentQty)
FROM
  tblIssueCommsItem
  INNER JOIN tblCommsItem
    ON tblIssueCommsItem.ItemID = tblCommsItem.ItemID
  INNER JOIN tblIssueCommsEqp
    ON tblIssueCommsItem.EqpID = tblIssueCommsEqp.EqpID
  INNER JOIN tblSetInfo
    ON tblSetInfo.EqpID = tblIssueCommsEqp.EqpID
WHERE
  SetID = 11
  AND (
        cardNo = 'TK 14'
        OR cardNo = ''
      )
  AND cardNo != 'Unassigned'
  AND tblIssueCommsItem.VoucherNo = 100006102
  AND tblIssueCommsEqp.currentQty > 0
GROUP BY  
  tblIssueCommsItem.ItemID,
  cardNo
ORDER BY
  cardNo
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT tblIssueCommsItem.ItemID, cardNo, q.currentQty 
FROM tblIssueCommsItem 
INNER JOIN tblCommsItem ON tblIssueCommsItem.ItemID = tblCommsItem.ItemID 
INNER JOIN 
(
    select EqpID, MAX(currentQty) as currentQty
    from tblIssueCommsEqp 
    group by EqpID
    having max(currentQty) > 0
) q ON tblIssueCommsItem.EqpID = q.EqpID  
INNER JOIN tblSetInfo ON tblSetInfo.EqpID = tblIssueCommsEqp.EqpID 
WHERE SetID = 11 AND (cardNo = 'TK 14' OR cardNo = '') 
    AND tblIssueCommsItem.VoucherNo = 100006102
    -- The below line is redundant, though it may still be useful in matching an index
    -- AND cardNo != 'Unassigned'   
ORDER BY cardNo, serial
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help. I think including *max function* will help and since you include *max* built-in function, remove *tblIssueCommsEqp.currentQty > 0 condition* in the *where clause.*

```
SELECT tblIssueCommsItem.ItemID, cardNo, Max(tblIssueCommsEqp.currentQty) 
FROM tblIssueCommsItem 
INNER JOIN tblCommsItem ON tblIssueCommsItem.ItemID = tblCommsItem.ItemID 
INNER JOIN tblIssueCommsEqp ON tblIssueCommsItem.EqpID = tblIssueCommsEqp.EqpID  
INNER JOIN tblSetInfo ON tblSetInfo.EqpID = tblIssueCommsEqp.EqpID 
WHERE SetID = 11 
AND (cardNo = 'TK 14' OR cardNo = '') 
AND cardNo != 'Unassigned' 
AND tblIssueCommsItem.VoucherNo = 100006102 
ORDER BY cardNo, serial;
```